# How to remove remote origin from branch name after converting from svn to git

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I am trying to convert an svn repository to git and I have mostly accomplished what I needed by doing the following:

```
git svn init https://svn.server.com/repos/my_repo --stdlayout
git svn fetch
```

I also found a way to convert all SVN branches to local Git branches:

```
for branch in `git branch -r | grep -v tags`; do
    git branch $branch $branch
done
```

However, now I am stuck with a list of branches that look like this:

```
origin/1.3
origin/1.4
origin/1.5
origin/1.6
origin/1.7
origin/1.8
origin/2.0
```

What I'd really like to end up with is branch names that look like this:

```
1.3
1.4
1.5
1.6
1.7
1.8
2.0
```

I've tried looking into git filter-branch, but I'm not sure if that is exactly what I want. I also tried to specify my layout more manually like this:

```
git svn clone --trunk=/trunk --branches=/branches --tags=/tags https://svn.server.com/repos/my_repo
```

but this did not work either. It gave me the same results with `origin/` before every branch name. I just wanted to know if it's possible to make these branch name changes without having to re-clone the entire repo again.

Here is the output of running `git branch -a`:

```
git branch -a
* master
  origin/1.3
  origin/1.4
  origin/1.5
  origin/1.6
  origin/1.7
  origin/1.8
  origin/2.0
```

Comment: When you run `git branch -a` what do you see?  Can you edit your question and include the output from this?

Comment: You can rename a branch like this `git branch -m old_name new_name` or rename the branch you are standing in by omitting old_name. In the same loop you are already using if you like. Would that be a solution?

Comment: Added output from `git branch -a`. I was wondering if a simple rename was all I needed to do, but will it preserve the history?

Comment: @Mr.Christer your solution worked for me. I used awk to strip off the `origin/` but I was able to rename all the branches with your command and then push them correctly. Thank you!

Comment: @user3270760 Great! I added a solution with sed instead of awk, but the idea is the same. Consider marking it as an answer if you agree that it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to add

```
git branch -m old_name new_name
```

to the loop so that the part of the bash script becomes

```
for branch in `git branch -r | grep -v tags`; do
    new_branch=$(echo $branch | sed 's/origin\///')
    git branch $branch $branch
    git branch -m $branch $new_branch
done
```

It can be made prettier but it gets the job done and shows that you can rename branches.